# Stack Overflow question is not showing user's profile

Tags: discussion, support

[This Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)  is not showing the user's profile. So does it mean the user is deleted? If the user profile is deleted in this question and if I upvote for it then who will receive reputation?

Comment: Yes, the user no longer exists. No one gets reputation if the question is up voted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you see a post with the user card grayed-out like this, then that means the user who originally posted that content has had their account deleted. There are several reasons why a user might be deleted: they might have asked for their account to be deleted, or their account might have been removed because they violated the Terms of Service.

Another possibility is that the user has asked for the post to be *dissociated* from their user account, thus effectively anonymizing it. This is your right, provided under the Terms of Service and the content license. (Although that obviously didn't happen in this particular case, since the user's original display name is still used there, which isn't very anonymous.)

Either way, your votes on the post will not cause any reputation change, because there is no user associated with the post. However, they will still change the score of the post, which affects, if nothing else, how it is sorted, so it still makes sense to vote on these posts.